# How to improve the resolution of a raster plot?

Tags: r, resolution, netcdf

Here is my data: https://github.com/dschmidt42/Benguela_Chla_Danielle_Schmidt.

What I've done so far:

```
chl_data <- "cmems_mod_glo_bgc_my_0.25_P1M-m_1673881119174.nc"
rast_chl_data <- rast(chl_data)
rast_chl_data <- seq(1, nlyr(rast_chl_data), 3) 
chl2 <- r[[rast_chl_data]]
chl_mean <- app(chl2, mean)
plot(chl_mean, 
     main = "Mean Chl a over 26 years",
     xlab = "Longitude",
     ylab = "Latitude")
```

[image]

Here is the resulting plot. The resolution is quite small so it's very blocky. Can I change the resolution or is that as high as it goes?

Comment: This appears to the resolution of the original data. You could consider interpolating it

Answer (score 1):

As @RobertWilson said, you should try interpolation. At least when I look at the data with ncview, the "repl" or no interpolation shows figure like this:

[image]

which has original pixel-wise resolution and does not look very nice (although, it has its values as it's not interpolated and one can see the "true" value immediately).

As soon as we switch on interpolation ("bi-lin" in ncview), the figure is like this:
[image]

It's smooth and nice to look at, but the values are diluted.

Another way to get similar behaviour is to use filled contour maps instead of pixel maps. You can take a look at examples in https://r-charts.com/correlation/contour-plot/ .